# Format Milliseconds aswell in Lua?

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I'm making a timer for a game & it works perfectly fine, but I just want it to show the milliseconds.

I tried to ask AI and it was horribly wrong. (Incorrect syntax, missing numbers...)

This is what I have `string.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)`

Comment: Heyo, how are you getting the variables for hours, minutes, and seconds? Is there anything more to your code sample?

Comment: Try ```os.clock()``` and use variables to set or reset your timers depending on the runtime.